# How to check if all the extendend stored procedures (xp_) are enabled or disabled?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

These are the stored procedures that I want to check if they are enabled or disabled.

- xp_availablemedia
- xp_cmdshell
- xp_deletemail
- xp_dirtree
- xp_dropwebtask
- xp_enumerrorlogs
- xp_enumgroups
- xp_findnextmsg
- xp_fixeddrives
- xp_getnetname
- xp_logevent
- xp_loginconfig
- xp_makewebtask
- xp_regread
- xp_readerrorlog
- xp_readmail
- xp_runwebtask
- xp_sendmail
- xp_servicecontrol
- xp_sprintf
- xp_sscanf
- xp_startmail
- xp_stopmail
- xp_grantlogin
- xp_revokelogin
- xp_logininfo
- xp_subdirs
- xp_regaddmultistring
- xp_regdeletekey
- xp_regdeletevalue
- xp_regenumkeys
- xp_regenumvalues
- xp_regremovemultistring
- xp_regwrite

I found a code for xp_cmdshell which works perfectly but not sure on how to use it on the other xp_

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(value, value_in_use)) AS config_value 
FROM  sys.configurations 
WHERE  name = N'xp_cmdshell'
```

It will output zero if it is disabled and 1 if it is enabled. How can I use this on the other xp_ ?

Comment: Most of the extended stored procedures you mention *cannot* be disabled; SQL Server relies upon them for internal functionality.  `xp_cmdshell` is an anomaly in this regard; it is disabled out-of-the-box since it is considered a security vulnerability when enabled.

Comment: There are a few others (`SELECT * FROM sys.configurations
WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE N'%xp%';`) but I agree with @Max - most of these can't be disabled anyway.